# GRE past papers

Tags: reference-request, education, online-resources

As it is required for most students who wish to do a Ph.D in maths in the US to sit the GRE subject specific mathematics exam, I hope this question will be of interest to the mathematical community and will not be closed.

Essentially, the exam was "rescaled" (made more difficult) in 2001 and I have only been able to find 2 past "rescaled" papers, one of which is available on the official website, the other available [here](http://www.math.ucsb.edu/mathclub/GRE/GRE9768.pdf) (this link being unvalid, another is [GRE9768.pdf](https://www.geneseo.edu/~johannes/GRE9768.pdf)). Are other past papers available elsewhere? Thanks.

EDIT: In actual fact, the exam was not made more difficult (see comments), so any past paper would be of interest.

Comment: This may be one of the documents you've already found: http://www.ets.org/Media/Tests/GRE/pdf/gre_0809_math_practice_book.pdf

Comment: My impression was that rescaling didn't change the difficulty of the questions, only the way the scores were computed.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have heard from many people that past exams for the math subject test are notoriously hard to find. It might be better to try to work your way around this issue while you're waiting to see if anybody has any tests in possession.

Comment: @Nate: Well before the rescaling a large percentage got perfect score (about 18% I think), whereas now about 1% get perfect score, so presumably the average question difficulty increased, given that the number of questions and exam time remained unchanged.

Comment: @Justin: Yes, but it was my understanding that a "perfect" score did/does not necessarily correspond to answering every question correctly, just to reaching some threshold that presumably was raised.  But I have no evidence to cite so I may be wrong.

Comment: Indeed, the first page of the link you cite says in bold, **the contents of the test will not change**.

Comment: Ok, this is good news, since now ANY past paper is relevant. Thank you for clearing this up.

Comment: Mostly they don't release past exams, so that the same questions can be re-used for norming purposes.  This helps them in their statistics, for example to keep the difficulty as constant as possible.  And I think this is something that we should not try to thwart.

Comment: I have updated the links in my answers, the old ones were not working anymore

Answer (score 4):

[EDIT: updated the link] I hope I understand the exact question. The version you have provided is "after October 1, 2001". On the very same site, you could  find the following links (which do not work anymore, only kept for the record):

- a version with copyright in 1990, 1991, 1993: http://www.math.ucsb.edu/mathclub/GRE/GRE9367.pdf
- a version with copyright in 1986: http://www.math.ucsb.edu/mathclub/GRE/GRE8767.pdf

They were working at the time of answering. I leave the initial links as they can provide clues to find other copies. Indeed, looking for 'GRE8767.pdf', I obtained new links:

- https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/abeeson/GRE/GRE8767.pdf
- https://www.geneseo.edu/~johannes/GRE8767.pdf

Same for "GRE9367.pdf"
- https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/abeeson/GRE/GRE9367.pdf

Comment: Your link is not opening

Comment: The first three links are not working, I wonder if you can provide an alternative to get them.

Comment: The last ones are working copies